# end of month/year data in tibco spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have the following dataset in tibco spotfire:

[Original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIlzt.png)

I want to bring the amount of item in the beginning of each month for each row and get the following result:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBffJ.png)

Any suggestions?

The dataset looks like this: I have got maximum amount for previous month, but I want to get the amount of the last day of the previous month.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJVXN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it via an intermediate column (as Spotfire's OVER does not accept expressions).

First calculate the year and month like this:
(assuming the format of your date is known and stable)
[YearMonth] is :

```
Integer(Concatenate(Substring(String([Date]),7,4),Substring(String([Date]),4,2)))
```

then your [Previous Month] is:

```
Max([Amount]) over (Intersect(Previous([YearMonth]),[BRANCH],[CLASS]))
```

and your [Diff] is:

```
[Amount] - [Previous Month]
```

Revised after comment 19 August:

change the Max to ValueForMax and insert the day of the month, so that the formula calculates the value
corresponding to the last recorded day for that month:

```
        ValueForMax(DayOfMonth([Date]),[Amount]) over (Intersect(Previous([YearMonth]),[BRANCH],[CLASS]))
```

Revised after comments 6 October:

if Substring(..) is not available, here is an alternative solution:

Create a new column (to make the expressions understandable): [StringMonth] as:

```
If(LongInteger(Month([Date]))>10,String(LongInteger(Month([Date]))), Concatenate('0',String(LongInteger(Month([Date])))))
```

Then calculate your [YearMonth] as:

```
Integer(Concatenate(Year([Date]),[StringMonth]))
```

Comment: Thanks Gaia, it is helpful. But max([Amount]) does not return the correct data since I have multiple rows with the intersection of those criteria. Let's say, I have 100 for 29/06/2022 and 60 for 30/06/2022. Max function returns 100 whereas I want to have 60 - end of month figure.

Comment: Please share a sample dataset that reflects your use case

Comment: I included the resulting dataset above. Please have a look

Comment: Gaia, I applied the method you mentioned, it works. There is a minor mistake, however, I hope you can help to solve it. YearMonth column returns 202210 for october-22, but in the Previous([YearMonth]) function, it takes it as 20221 (jan-22) and returns the data of December 2021 (previous month). How can I solve this case?

Comment: can you show me how your date is formatted (and is it a datetime datatype)? I was assuming format 01/01/2022.

Comment: Integer(Concatenate(Year([REPORT_DATE]),LongInteger(Month([REPORT_DATE])))) is my formula which returns 202210. And my Report_Date column format is datetime '10/16/2009'

Comment: you used a different formula than the one I suggested. Can you try mine? From my tests, it works.

Comment: I do not have substring formula, as I use 5.5 version. The result is the same, I think. In my case I works for all other dates from january till september, but not in October.

Comment: ok, the problem is that LongInteger would give you 1 instead of 01 for January. Let me think if there is a workaround without SubString

Comment: I would create a new column (to make the expressions understandable):
[StringMonth] as:
If(LongInteger(Month([Date]))>10,String(LongInteger(Month([Date]))),Concatenate('0',String(LongInteger(Month([Date])))))
Then calculate your [YearMonth] as:
Integer(Concatenate(Year([Date]),[StringMonth]))

Comment: used similar logic, Gaia. It works fine. Thanks for prompt response. case  when Month([REPORT_DATE])<10 then Integer(Concatenate(Year([REPORT_DATE]),"0",String(Month([REPORT_DATE])))) else 
Integer(Concatenate(Year([REPORT_DATE]),String(Month([REPORT_DATE])))) end

Comment: ok great, can you accept the answer now, I have revised it.